# crontab not working with gsutil

Tags: bash, backup, cron

I have the following bash script to run a postgres backup, compress it en push it to a google cloud bucket. This is installed on a google cloud VM so I have access to gsutil. The service account of this vm also gives me permission to add files to a bucket.

```
// /home/myusername/bash/pgbackup.sh
#!/bin/sh

FILENAME="backup_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").sql";
PGPASSWORD=pg_password pg_dump -U pg_username db_name > $FILENAME;
tar -cvzf $FILENAME.tar.gz $FILENAME;
gsutil cp $FILENAME.tar.gz gs://bucket-name/$FILENAME;
rm -f $FILENAME $FILENAME.tar.gz;
```

The crontab command looks like this:

```
// sudo crontab -e
0 * * * * /home/myusername/bash/pgbackup.sh >> backups.log
```

The crontab doesn't work. It runs because I get a backups.log file after an hour, but this file is empty. But there is no file in the bucket. When I run the shell-script by itself, it works. I get gsutil-output and I can find a backup in my bucket.

For testing purposes, I ran this crontab every minute, I don't get a backup in my bucket and I don't get any output in backups.log.

The script previously had other content (locally saving the backup) and then it worked, so I know I'm calling it correctly (it's in the sudo crontab file).

**Edit: solution**

The solution (?) was to add the absolute paths to the files.

```
FILENAME = "/home/username/backup_$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S").sql";
```

Comment: Try redirecting errors to the backups.log too ... adding  ` 2>&1 `   to the end of the cron-line. Then you maybe can see what fails.

Comment: "I have the following bash script"? Why does it start with `#!/bin/sh` and not `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: @waltinator, now you're just being pedantic ;-) `#!/bin/sh` can still be a bash script, but a POSIX compliant one. Hardly an issue for the question at hand..